# Apigility Production Mode - Fatal Error in ModuleAutoloader.php on line 147

Tags: php, api, laminas-api-tools

I'm getting this error with development mode disabled. Can someone help me? I'm using version `1.4`

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/matthew/sandbox/zf-apigility-skeleton-1.3.3/module/Application/Module.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\api_linktel\vendor\zendframework\zend-loader\src\ModuleAutoloader.php
>   on line 147
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/matthew/sandbox/zf-apigility-skeleton-1.3.3/module/Application/Module.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\api_linktel\vendor\zendframework\zend-loader\src\ModuleAutoloader.php
>   on line 147

Comment: did you by any chance run a composer update?

Comment: `ls '/home/matthew/sandbox/zf-apigility-skeleton-1.3.3/module/Application/` is Module.php there?

Comment: Hi! Yes. I ran the composer update. This '/home/matthew/sandbox/zf-apigility-skeleton-1.3.3/module/Ap plication /' is not the directory for my project. This only happens with the development mode disabled.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED** - The problem was with the cache generated by the application. No data / cache directory exists a file that writes a configuration of the modules.

I cleaned the contents of the data/cache/module-classmap-cache.application.module.cache.php file and it worked.

```
<?php
  return array(
 -  'Application\\Module' => '/home/matthew/sandbox/zf-apigility-skeleton-1.3.3/module/Application/Module.php'      
);
```